# how to add the html tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have written the following function using this i am showing ajax response in Html

```
function loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1/get_scroll_rec/",
            cache: false,               
            data:'',
            success: function(response){
                var obj = JSON.parse(response);
                try{
                    var str = '';
                    var items=[];   
                    $.each(obj[0], function(i,val){ 

                                                    //Here display code

                            items.push($('<div id="recent">').html(val.Title));
                            items.push($('<h1>').html(val.name));
                            items.push($('<p>').html(val.desciption));
                            items.push($('<div id="recent_created" class="recent_created">').html(val.added_on));
                    }); 

                    $('#recent_rightwrapper1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        $(this).append(str).fadeIn('slow').fadeIn(3000);
                        $('#recent_rightwrapper1').css({backgroundColor: ''});
                        $('#recent_rightwrapper1').append.apply($('#recent_rightwrapper1'), items);
                    }).css({backgroundColor: ''});

                }catch(e) {     
                    alert('Exception while request..');
                }       
            },
            error: function(){                      
                alert('Error while request..');
            }
         });


    }

});
```

HOw can i add some HTMl tag to this display area code
like (changes to 1st line "h1" tag added, change to 2nd line "a" tag added)
want to add div without data at last line no 5.

```
1> items.push($('<div id="recent"><h1>').html(val.Title));
2> items.push($('<h1><a href="" target="_blank">').html(val.name));
3> items.push($('<p>').html(val.desciption));
4> items.push($('<div id="recent_created" class="recent_created">').html(val.added_on));
5> items.push($('<div id="blank">')
```

Answer (score 0):

You *append* sub nodes to an existing element via [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#yourRoot").append($('<div id="blank">'));
```

**EDIT:** The `append` works on any jQuery object, also on one which you just created by supplying an HTML text. So if you want to append the empty `div` to the element in the first line you just do the following:

```
var $firstLine = $('<div id="recent"><h1>').html(val.Title);
var $lastLine = $('<div id="blank">');
$firstLine.append($lastLine);
items.push($firstLine);
```

Comment: :want to add extra Html tag to line 1,2